# python updating a value while using star

Tags: python, a-star

I am wondering why my value "player_action_input" does not get updated.
The value keep remains as 0. I know I could use (player_action_input) instead of (*info) but I want to try to learn how to update a value using *. ### Also if I run this I get 2 outcomes.

```
player_action_input = 0
info = [player_action_input]

def player_action(*info):    
    while True:   
        try:
            player_action_input = int(input("Enter 0 to stay, 1 to go Up, or 2 to go Down: "))
        except ValueError:
            print("You have entered an incorrect number, please try again")
            continue

        if player_action_input == 0:
            ready_speech(*info)         

        if player_action_input == 1:
            player_action_input = player_action_input + 1
            print ("Thank You, you chose to go up")
            count(*info)

        if player_action_input == 2:
            player_action_input = player_action_input + 2
            print ("Thank You, you chose to go down")
            count(*info)

        else:
            print ("You have entered an incorrect number, please try again")
            continue
        break

def count(*info):
    print (player_action_input)

player_action(*info)
```

Comment: The `player_action_input` inside of `player_action()` is a local variable, entirely unrelated to the global `player_action_input` variable.  Passing a variable as a parameter to a function (even in the strange way you're doing it) ONLY makes its existing value available to the function; it does not grant the function any way to modify the variable's value.

Comment: So yes, that is why I am asking that question on how to modify it if possible.